# Cordova: Media plugin record audio empty file

Tags: cordova

I am using `cordova-plugin-media` to record audio. I set the path into `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory`.

I have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

This is how I record my audio:

```
let src = app.path + new Date().getTime() + app.extension;

$scope.mediaRec = new Media(src,
    (data) => {
        let img = '<div><audio type="audio/aac" controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="' + src + '"></audio><br/></div><div><br/></div>';
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, img);
    },            
    (error) => {});

$scope.mediaRec.startRecord();

$timeout(function() {
    $scope.mediaRec.stopRecord();
    $scope.mediaRec.release();
},5000);
```

When I check inside my storage, the file is being created, but the file is empty. It has 0 bytes size. It cannot be played.

I used different file types `.aac, .mp3, .3gp, .wav` but all of them are the same.

How can I save the file successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I currently record voice in Cordova and VueJs by these methods:

```
async startRecording() {
  const audioFileName = `${uid()}.mp3`;
  let fileSrc;
  try {
    fileSrc = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystem => {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(audioFileName, {
          create: true,
          exclusive: false,
        }, fileEntry => {
          resolve(fileEntry.toURL());
        }, reject);
      }, reject);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    this.$logger.catchError(e);
    return;
  }
  this.fileSrc = fileSrc;
  // this.$logger.debug('fileSrc', fileSrc)
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  this.media = new Media(fileSrc, () => {
    // this.$logger.debug('media success', this.media)
  }, err => {
    this.$logger.debug('media error', err.message);
  });
  this.media.startRecord();
  this.state = 'recording';
},
stopRecording() {
  this.media.stopRecord();
  if (this.autoPlay) {
    this.media.play();
  }
  this.state = 'finish';
},
finishRecording() {
  this.$emit('input', this.fileSrc);
  this.state = 'start';
  this.media.release();
  this.media = null;
},
```

As you can see, first of all, I reserve a file path by `requestFileSystem` then pass it to the recording plugin. `new Media(fileSrc ...`

Comment: I give up using `cordova-plugin-media`, I am using `cordova-plugin-audioinput` now.

Comment: I was struggling a lot till find the way. Never give up, there is a way always ;-)